# jQuery-chosen library

Tags: jquery, jquery-chosen

Is there a way that I can see when a chosen script has been performed? I would like a function  that works like this:

```
$('#events-drop-down').chosen({}, function(event){
    // Perform something when chosen has been loaded.
});
```

Is there anyway that I can achieve this with chosen library?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, there is nothing asynchronous about the loading of the `chosen` plugin. The next line of code will not be run until all the actions there are complete.

```
$('#events-drop-down').chosen({});
console.log('Will be run after chosen has been applied');
```